# How convert text from shell to html?

Tags: python, linux

Probably it really easy and stupid question, but I'm new in Python, so deal with it

What I need to do - execute command in shell and output it as telegra.ph page

Problem - telegra.ph API ignores \n things and all outpot text in one line

Used Python Telegraph API wrapper - https://github.com/python273/telegraph

I understand it needs to convert my text to html-like and remove <p> tags, I've tried some scripts, but my program gave me error:

```
telegraph.exceptions.NotAllowedTag: span tag is not allowed
```

So, I've removed all span tags and got same result as if I've put without converting

Then I tried to use `replace("\n", "<p>")` but stucked in closing tags...

Code:

```
import subprocess

from telegraph import Telegraph

telegraph = Telegraph()
telegraph.create_account(short_name='1111')

tmp = subprocess.run("arp", capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True).stdout

print( '\n\n\n'+tmp+'\n\n\n\n')   ### debug line


response = telegraph.create_page(
    'Random',
    html_content= '<p>' + tmp + '</p>'
)

print('https://telegra.ph/{}'.format(response['path']))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest html equivalent to `\n` is the ["hard break" `<br/>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp).
It does not require closing, because it contains nothing, and directly signifies line break.

Assuming it is supported by telegra.ph, you could simply:

```
tmp.replace('\n', '<br/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to convert all intermediate newlines to individual <p>-sections:

```
tmp = "</p><p>".join(tmp.split("\n"))
```

`tmp.split("\n")` splits the string into an array of lines.

`"</p><p>".join(...)` glues everything together again, closing the previous <p>-section and starting a new one.

This way, the example works for me and line breaks are correctly displayed on the page.

EDIT: As the other answer suggests, of course you can also use 
 tags. It depends on what you want to achieve!

Comment: This is actually a good solution, but to make it complete you would need to prepend the first opening `<p>` and append the last closing `</p>` to the output of `join`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me, why does the `telegraph` module replace newlines with spaces. In this case it seems reasonable to disable this functionality.

```
import subprocess
import re

import telegraph
from telegraph import Telegraph

telegraph.utils.RE_WHITESPACE = re.compile(r'([ ]{10})', re.UNICODE)

telegraph = Telegraph()
telegraph.create_account(short_name='1111')

tmp = subprocess.run("/usr/sbin/arp", 
                     capture_output=True, 
                     text=True, 
                     shell=True).stdout
  
response = telegraph.create_page(
    'Random',
    html_content = '<pre>' + tmp + '</pre>'
)

print('https://telegra.ph/{}'.format(response['path']))
```

Would output

[image: arp output formatted for telegraph]

that comes close to actual formatted `arp` output.